# Generic type for play case classes

Tags: json, forms, scala, playframework-2.2

I am using play 2.2.0 built with Scala 2.10.2 (running Java 1.7.0_45).  Most of the routes/endpoints in my application receive a json request, parse parse the data into a case class using a form and then do business logic on the received data.  I have abstracted this.  It works, but one thing I don't like is that I am casting the case class instance to java.lang.Object.  Then, the specific handler function has to re-cast the case class instance back to its original type.

I'm pretty new to play/scala.  Is there a cleaner way in scala to change the signature on my handler function so that casting isn't necessary.  It feels wrong to have to cast and then re-cast back.  Perhaps this is just the price of abstraction in this case (no pun intended)?

The code below has:

1. The RefreshTokenController which calls the plumbing method.  Notice the unnecessary cast.
2. The ControllerUtil.handleJsonRequest method which does an unnecessary cast.

I think what I'm looking for is correct usage of scala generics.  This doesn't compile, but something like:

```
    def handleJsonRequest(form: Form[T], handlerFunction: (T) => SimpleResult, request: Request[Object]):     SimpleResult {
```

Look for the "TODO" comments in the code below.  Bonus points if you have a better, more "play-like" way of abstracting the parsing and business logic.  For example, should I have my own application specific Action?

```
{"paramA": "paramA_Value", "paramB": "paramB_Value"}


object RefreshTokenController extends Controller {

  private case class RequestData(paramA: String, paramB: String)

  private val requestForm = Form(
    mapping(
      "paramA" -> nonEmptyText,
      "ParamB" -> nonEmptyText
    )(RequestData.apply)(RequestData.unapply)
  )

  def myEndPoint = Action(ControllerUtil.formOrJsonParser) {
    request =>  {
      val response = ControllerUtil.handleJsonRequest(requestForm, requestHandlerFunction, request)
      response
    }
  }

  val requestHandlerFunction: (Object) => SimpleResult = processRequest

  def processRequest(refreshDataObj: Object) : SimpleResult = {
    //TODO: Yuck, how can I get rid of the unnecessary cast
    val refreshData: RequestData = refreshDataObj.asInstanceOf[RequestData]

    //Business logic removed since it's not relevant
  }
}


object ControllerUtil {

  /**
   * Handles the plumbing of parsing a json request and applying business logic.
   */
  def handleAsyncJsonRequest(form: Form[_],
    handlerFunction: (Object) => Future[SimpleResult],
    request: Request[Object]): Future[SimpleResult] = {
    // Convert the request body to JSON even if using URL-Form-Encoding
    val formData: Object = parseUsingForm(form, request)
    handlerFunction(formData)
  }

  /**
   * Handles the plumbing of parsing a json request and applying business logic.
   *
   */
  def handleJsonRequest(form: Form[_],
    handlerFunction: (Object) => SimpleResult,
    request: Request[Object]): SimpleResult = {
    //TODO: How can I change the function signature so I can avoid casting/recasting.
    val formData: Object = parseUsingForm(form, request)
    handlerFunction(formData)
  }

  def parseUsingForm(form: Form[_], request: Request[Object]): Object = {
    val jsonData: JsValue = parseRequestToJson(request)
    parseUsingForm(form, jsonData)
  }

  def parseUsingForm(form: Form[_], jsData: JsValue): Object = {
    form.bind(jsData).fold(
      formWithErrors => {
        val error = Results.BadRequest(formWithErrors.errorsAsJson)
        throw new UserErrorException(error)
      },
      parsedData => {
        //TODO: Yuck, I don't like having to cast here.
        val formData: Object = parsedData.asInstanceOf[Object]
        formData
      }
    )
  }

  def parseRequestToJson(request: Request[Object]): JsValue = {
    var jsonLoginRequest: JsValue = null
    request.body match {
      case json: JsObject => jsonLoginRequest = json
      case form: Map[String, Seq[String]] => jsonLoginRequest = Json.toJson(form.map {
        case (k, v) => (k, v.head)
      })
    }

    jsonLoginRequest
  }

  /**
   *  parse html encoded form containing json data or String json data
   */
  val formOrJsonParser = parse.using {
    request =>
      request.contentType.map(_.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH)) match {
        case Some("application/json") | Some("text/json") => parse.json
        case Some("application/x-www-form-urlencoded") | Some("text/x-www-form-urlencoded") =>
          parse.urlFormEncoded
        case _ =>
          parse.error(Future.successful(Results.UnsupportedMediaType("Invalid content type specified")))
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Which version of Play are you using?

Comment: play 2.2.0 built with Scala 2.10.2 (running Java 1.7.0_45)

Comment: Typically, when receiving a request with a JSON body you'd deserialize it into a case class using a [`play.api.libs.json.Reads[T]`](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.Reads). I'm confused with why you appear to be using a form to parse JSON data.  Can you update the question to be specific about exactly what format your incoming data is in?

Comment: I just updated.  I think the form is to validate the input data, which is coming from an end user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This short answer as to why you need casting is that you're not really using the Scala type system, instead passing `Object` everywhere because your forms are given as a wildcard type `Form[_]`. The form must be parameterized with the type of object it's defining a mapping for - if you want to use them in a generic manner use them something like this:

```
/** 
 * Given a form and a handler, produce a result.
 */
def parseForm[T](form: Form[T], handler: T => SimpleResult)(implicit request: Request[AnyContent]): SimpleResult = {
  form.bindFromRequest.fold(
    errForm => BadRequest(errForm.errorsAsJson),
    item => handler(item)
  )
}
```

But forms are really meant for formUrlEncoded data, and you're receiving JSON so they're the wrong tool for this job.

I think there's a much easier way to do what you want, assuming (based on your code):

- You're always getting JSON data
- The content type might not always be JSON

In this case you can use the `BodyParsers.tolerantJson` parser, which will give you a `JsValue` to deserialise but won't bother checking the content type.

You can validate and parse the incoming JSON using a `Reads[T]`. Something like this should get you started:

```
package controllers

import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.libs.json.{Reads, JsError, Json}


object RefreshTokenController extends Controller {

  case class RequestData(paramA: String, paramB: String)

  object RequestData {
    implicit val reads: Reads[RequestData] = Json.reads[RequestData]
  }

  def myEndPoint = Action(BodyParsers.parse.tolerantJson) { request =>
    processJson(request.body, processItem)
  }

  def processJson[T](json: JsValue, handler: T => SimpleResult)(implicit rd: Reads[T]): SimpleResult = {
    json.validate[T].fold(
      err => BadRequest(JsError.toFlatJson(err)),
      item => handler(item)
    )
  }

  def processItem(item: RequestData) : SimpleResult = {
    Ok(s"Fancy business logic with $item")
  }
}
```

The `implicit val reads: Reads[RequestData] = Json.reads[RequestData]` defines a reads type to parse/validate JSON into your data case class. The `implicit` means that, because it's in the companion object of your class, it'll be found automatically whenever you try and validate an object of this type, but it can also be specified explicitly. If the validation fails you'll get errors describing what's wrong (e.g. missing path `paramA`) which we send back in a `BadRequest`.

When we validate the incoming JSON we use a the `fold` function, which accepts to arguments: a function to process the error and a function to process the correct result.

Some extra Scala advice:

- Use `AnyRef` instead of Java's `Object`, but doing so is usually a sign that you're subverting the type system in some way.
- Don't use `null`, ever, unless you're interacting with a Java API and absolutely can't avoid it. Instead use `Option[String]` whenever something could legitimately be "not there".

Comment: Thanks for the responses and scala tips.  I originally started with something very close to what you posted.  From there, I wanted to abstract/remove duplicate code because I noticed all my actions have much logic in common.  The ControllerUtil logic will be used for many endpoints/Actions.  I think what I need here are scala generics ... something like:   def handleJsonRequest(form: Form[T], handlerFunction: (T) => SimpleResult, request: Request[Object]): SimpleResult { ...

Comment: I have expanded my answer, but I think this question is too sprawling. If you have a specific problem with Scala generics try and ask that separately. Otherwise try and narrow this one down a bit more. Best of luck!